# Is it safe to delete the ESB Toolkit SOAP receive locations?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, esb-toolkit-2.1, bhm

Is it safe to delete the ESB SOAP receive locations, and leave just the WCF-WSHttp ones?

Reason I ask; the BizTalk Health Monitor is flagging that the SOAP adapter is deprecated in BizTalk 2010, yet the ESB Toolkit 2.1 is still using it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it safe to delete the ESB Toolkit Receive Locations...hahaha....I'd prefer they not be installed in the first place...;)

All kidding (well, not really) aside, if your not using them, then yes, by all means delete them.

However, the higher level answer is that you should just treat the BTHM warning as just that, warnings and add these to the expected warnings list.  A clean BTHM report doesn't get you anything other than a clean report.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Agree, a clean report is just a clean report, but I'm concerned that we're potentially using the deprecated adapter